# html/css: white spaces/collapsed container in horizontal list

Tags: html, css, list

I'm trying to create a horizontal menu for my webisite. It's not that difficult, but I'm running into two problems, which brake my design.

I can do it in two ways:

1). by setting

```
#menu li { 
display: inline-block;
}
```

like I did here: http://jsfiddle.net/l0ner/HPpgG/.

It works and looks like I want but there is a white space between each element, which  breaks the design. I could remove the space by putting all list elements in one line, but it's not exactly an elegant solution.
I know I could set the `<ul>` font size to 0, and then restore it in `<li>` but it feels too much like a dirty hack to me, and I'd like to keep the css 'magic' minimal.

How do I remove those spaces?

2). by setting

```
#menu li {
display: block;
float: left;
}
```

Like I did here: http://jsfiddle.net/l0ner/HPpgG/1/

But like this the `<div>` container collapses and I loose the white background for the menu, which makes whole thing unreadable.

How I can make the container uncollpased?

Comment: One thing you could do is add overflow:hidden; to the ul in the second option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HPpgG/5/)

```
#menu ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow:auto;
}
#menu li {
    float: left;
    list-style:none;
}
```

You need to set the overflow of the `ul` to `auto` or `hidden`

Comment: set the overflow of the ul to auto OR hidden

Answer (score 0):

For your first example, the white space in between the `li` elements is literally caused by white space in your HTML - the line breaks in between your `</li>` and `<li>` tags. If you remove this, the white space will go away.

Alternatively, for your second example, you can stretch the parent element to 'clear' the floated elements. There are a couple of ways to do this (google 'clearfix' for a few examples), but the easiest way would be to use `overflow: hidden` on the parent element.

Answer (score 0):

Just make the 'overflow' of your `<div>` hidden.

```
#menu {
    background: #fff;
    color: #000;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

[Fiddled here](http://jsfiddle.net/HPpgG/8/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a pseudo-element to do a clearfix on the `<ul>` without additional markup

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tyriar/dNZyR/)

```
#menu ul:after {
    clear:both;
    content:"";
    display:block;
}
```